# Read txt file line by line

Tags: vbscript

I am having trouble of making the vbscript to read the text line by line.
This is the steps the code should do:

1. Read folder.txt
2. Open the file listed in folder.txt
3. Echo the contents inside of test.txt
4. Read folder-list.txt
5. Open the file listed in folder-list.txt
6. Open dirlist.txt and echo line by line

An example of what folder.txt contains:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\ArtistCG\[ Go! Go! Heaven!!]_____________25 -______ ___- [525067]\test.txt
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\ArtistCG\[12CUT] _____ (Gakkou no Kaidan) [518382]\test.txt
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\ArtistCG\[2____] _____!__CD__________ [521206]\test.txt
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\ArtistCG\[Ability] _____________________ [514182]\test.txt
```

An example of what folder-list.txt contains:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\ArtistCG\[ Go! Go! Heaven!!]_____________25 -______ ___- [525067]\dirlist.txt
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\ArtistCG\[12CUT] _____ (Gakkou no Kaidan) [518382]\dirlist.txt
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\ArtistCG\[2____] _____!__CD__________ [521206]\dirlist.txt
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\ArtistCG\[Ability] _____________________ [514182]\dirlist.txt
```

An example of what each dirlist.txt contains

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\ArtistCG\[ Go! Go! Heaven!!]_____________25 -______ ___- [525067]\00.jpg
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\ArtistCG\[ Go! Go! Heaven!!]_____________25 -______ ___- [525067]\a_01.jpg
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\ArtistCG\[ Go! Go! Heaven!!]_____________25 -______ ___- [525067]\a_02.jpg
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\ArtistCG\[ Go! Go! Heaven!!]_____________25 -______ ___- [525067]\a_03.jpg
```

And this is the vbscript code

```
Option Explicit

Dim objFSO, strTextFile, strData, strLine, arrLines, aniTextFile, aniData, aniLines, meLine, objTextFile, fso, inputFileList, sFolderName, fname
Dim iim1, iret, iret2, iret3, i
CONST ForReading = 1

strTextFile = "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\ArtistCG\folder.txt"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strData = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strTextFile,ForReading).ReadAll
arrLines = Split(strData,vbCrLf)

For Each strLine in arrLines
  strData = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strLine,ForReading).ReadAll
WScript.Echo strData

aniTextFile = "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\ArtistCG\folder-list.txt"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
aniData = objFSO.OpenTextFile(aniTextFile,ForReading).ReadAll
aniLines = Split(aniData,vbCrLf)

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set listFile = fso.OpenTextFile(aniLines).ReadAll
do while not listFile.AtEndOfStream 
    fName =  listFile.ReadLine()
    WScript.Echo fName
    Loop
Next
```

So far I only got steps 1 to 4 working but I can't get it to read dirlist.txt. Any solutions here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The line

```
Set listFile = fso.OpenTextFile(aniLines).ReadAll
```

won't work for two reasons:

- `Set` can only be used when assigning *objects* to variables, but `ReadAll` returns a *string*.
- `OpenTextFile()` expects a string, but `aniLines` is an *array* of strings.

To process all elements of the array, you could use something like this:

```
For Each line In aniLines
  ' read dirlist.txt file
Next
```

The question is how you want to read the `dirlist.txt` files. You could do the same as you did with the other files: read the entire content of the file and split it into an array:

```
listFile  = fso.OpenTextFile(line).ReadAll
listLines = Split(listFile, vbCrLf)
```

and then use another loop like the one above to process the fields of the array `listLines`. This approach is preferrable for small files, because the code is simpler.

Or you could use the `ReadLine` approach (which is preferrable when you have to process large files, because it avoids memory exhaustion):

```
Set listFile = fso.OpenTextFile(line)  ' <-- remove .ReadAll from this line!
Do Until listFile.AtEndOfStream
  fName = listFile.ReadLine
  ' do stuff with fName
Loop
```

I recommend using `Do Until` instead of `Do While Not`, because the semantic is the same, but the former is closer to natural language and thus easier to read.

Also it would be sufficient to instantiate a `FileSystemObject` object once at the beginning of the script and just use that instance in the rest of the script. It's pointless to instantiate it over and over again.

Comment: +1, though I'd suggest using `ReadLine` simply because it makes a lot more sense then a `ReadAll` & `Split`combo.

Comment: with Readline, it only reads until the vbLf Character, which can be wrong if your lines contain vbLF characters before vbCRLF. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/readline-method