# VBS Looping returning NEXT line then expected

Tags: loops, vbscript

I am trying to find a field value in a flat file, and set a variable based on that value.  Here is my code:

```
Set file = fso.OpenTextFile(DataFileName, 1)
do until file.AtEndOfStream
    if StrComp(left(file.readLine, 3) , "H23") = 0 Then
        WScript.Echo file.ReadLine
        If StrComp(Split(file.readLine, "~")(4) , "1") = 0 Then
            ExportMapName = "ExportMap_1"
        Else
            ExportMapName = "ExportMap_2"
        End If

    End If
loop
Wscript.Echo ExportMapName
```

However, when it gives me the `ReadLine` value, it shows `H24` like, it skips right over the `H23` line.  I'm sure I have my loops nested incorrectly, but I'm not able to find any where that gives me guidance. TIA!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read txt file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149698/read-txt-file-line-by-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `ReadLine` on the `TextStream` object returned by `OpenTextFile` advances the reader to the next line. A simplified illustration of your issue:

```
do until file.AtEndOfStream
    WScript.Echo file.ReadLine 'returns a line
    WScript.Echo file.ReadLine 'returns the next line
loop
```

Also notice the logic error: if the first `ReadLine` is the last line in the file, an error will occur on the second `ReadLine`.

Comment: Thanks @Rno, I set the file.ReadLine to a variable and was able to work through the conditionals with that!